# prevent Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) Attack in Java

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, csrf

Here is a sample of my web application. Does it vulnerable to Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) Attack? How can i prevent from CSRF?

here is my new.jsp for adding new user.

```
            <FORM NAME="Form" METHOD="post" ACTION="controller?event=PostNewUser">
                <TABLE WIDTH="655" BORDER="0" CELLPADDING="2" CELLSPACING="0" class="gray_background" align="center" >        
                    <TR><TD colspan="4" CLASS="text" align="left"><strong>Personal Details</strong></TD></TR>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="4">
                            <table >
                                <TR>
                                    <TD width="62" align="right" CLASS="text">Code :&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td width="144"><INPUT NAME="code" TYPE="text" id="code" VALUE="N" CLASS="password" maxlength="9"></td>
                                    <td width="66" align="right" CLASS="text">Name :&nbsp; </td>
                                    <TD width="144" align="left" CLASS="text"><input name="name" type="text" id="name" value="" class="password" maxlength="80">
                                    </TD>
                                    <TD width="44" align="right" CLASS="text">Email :&nbsp;</TD>
                                    <TD width="152" align="left" CLASS="text"><input name="email" type="text" id="email" value="" class="password" maxlength="70"></TD>
                                </TR>                       
                    <TR>
                        <TD colspan="4" CLASS="text" align="center"><INPUT NAME="submit" TYPE="submit" class="submit_button" VALUE="Create" ></TD>
                    </TR>        
                </TABLE>
            </FORM>
```

And here is my servlet.

```
 public class PostNewAgentEventHandler extends EventHandlerBase {

 protected void process(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

 String name = request.getParameter("name").trim();
 String agentCode = request.getParameter("code").trim();
 String email = request.getParameter("email").trim();
}
}
```

Comment: Since you haven't taken any steps to prevent it, yes it is. There is plenty of information available on how to prevent it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might consider using [OWASP CSRFGuard](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_CSRFGuard_Project). It's a Filter for servlet applications designed to prevent CSRF attacks.

Their web site design isn't brilliant. You can find the [Installation Guide](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/CSRFGuard_3_Installation), [User Manual](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/CSRFGuard_3_User_Manual) and other links by scrolling down to the bottom of the page.

Comment: OWASP is a great start, if you are enterprising enough, and are targeting working with Spring, I believe Spring 4 includes out of the box CSRF support. It can be trivially added, with an MVC interceptor, under 3.1+ I believe.

Comment: Yes, that's a good point. If you're using a framework, it's a good idea to look for anti-CSRF features there. But I get the impression from the question that Suniel is using plain servlets.

Comment: agreed - which is why I mentioned "enterprising enough"